# Running a JSF-2 page using embedded Jetty?

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, jsf-2, embedded-jetty

Is it possible to start up a JSF-2 page (assuming I have the *.html and backing bean) using embedded Jetty?

By Embedded Jetty I mean something like the following (but obviously coupled with a JSF page)

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler;

public class HelloHandler extends AbstractHandler
{
    public void handle(String target,Request baseRequest,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        baseRequest.setHandled(true);
        response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server(8080);
        server.setHandler(new HelloHandler());

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to solve this is to [use Arquillian](https://community.jboss.org/thread/157418?_sscc=t).

Answer (score 0):

Got it working using org.eclipse.jetty version 8.1.1.v20120215 and starting it programmatically from a main in Eclipse with Debug As..., it shows no errors in the Eclipse console and runs fine.

It also seems to require EXPRESSION_FACTORY context-param in web.xml if you want to use EL 2.2.

Additional infos: I use servlet 3.0 and jsf 2.1.7

If you use Maven watch out for the scopes of included libraries (runtime, compile, test,...).

Comment: I'm aware there are all kinds of ways to make this work with eclipse plugins and maven plugins. What I wanted was a pure Java version - something that can be kicked off from multiple execution hosts.